# Zookeeper is consuming more CPU in Clickhouse

Tags: apache-zookeeper, clickhouse

I am new to clickhouse and zookeeper.

I see that zookeeper leader is consuming more CPU. I am not sure what to check!

I checked load on clickhouse servers and it is normal.

ENV:

3 zookeepers
4 Clickhouse nodes

I am not sure what to check for the issue! Can someone help me what needs to be checked.

Answer (score 0):

It's expected that Zookeeper leader consumes more CPU.

> 3 zookeepers 4 Clickhouse nodes

For this setup I would expect that Zookeeper leader will consume 5% CPU, followers 3% CPU with 2CPU per ZK node setup.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! However, is there a way we can find what exactly is being executing on zookeeper leader node?

Comment: The leader in Apache ZooKeeper is responsible for handling client requests, coordinating updates, and managing the distributed consensus protocol. It performs additional tasks compared to followers, which primarily focus on replicating the state and forwarding requests to the leader.

Comment: Leader-Specific Tasks: The leader performs various administrative tasks, such as maintaining the server's membership, monitoring the health of followers, and managing leader election if the current leader fails. These tasks require additional CPU resources.

Comment: I got this! However, Zookeeper leader is consuming 90% CPU where as follower consuming 10 Percentage CPU.

I am not sure what zookeeper is doing extra other than the tasks you mentioned.

Comment: I see there is some fluctuation in ClickHouseMetrics_ZooKeeperRequest. Whenever this number go high load on zookeeper goes high.

Comment: how many Replicated tables do you have?

Comment: We have 74 replicated tables

Comment: there is a table zookeeper_log in CH. It's disabled by default. I would enable it at stage env (NOT PROD) and would check what requests are prevail.

Comment: Sure! I will enable and  update you the details.

Comment: How to enable zookeeper_log table?